# Passing arguments containing white space through a wrapper shell script to python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a wrapper script **command.sh** as main launch script for my python application, primarily to set some environment variables like `PYTHONPATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=lib64/python/side-packages
./command.py $*
```

**command.py** looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print sys.argv
```

Calling the wrapper script like

```
$ ./command.sh a "b c"
```

results in `['./command.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']`, where I need `['./command.py', 'a', 'b c']`

How can I pass parameters which contain spaces to the python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$@` instead of `$*`, and quote it with `"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=lib64/python/side-packages
./command.py "$@"
```

See [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), section "Special Parameters", for more information.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script/9995322#9995322 for more information on this.