# General function for suppressing output into bash -- spaced filenames

Tags: bash, output

I would like to write bash function to suppress output into command line in bash.

I have included a following into the $HOME/.bashrc

```
# suspend output to the terminal
noout(){
        $* &>/dev/null &
}
```

And as an example I have created alias for evince:

```
alias evince='noout evince'
```

This works just fine for files without spaces in the file names. However if I launch something like:

```
evince Jack\ London\ -\ The\ Star\ Rover.pdf
```

Bash splits the file names into several bits and evince opens several empty windows.

Thanks for any help to make it working.

Comment: What if you call it with `evince "Jack London ..."`? that is, having the parameter within double quotes?

Comment: The result is the same using the double quotes: it opens several empty windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
noout() {
    "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

I'm not sure why you want to do it in the background, but that's your choice.  The relevant aspect of my answer is the quotes and the use of `$@` instead of `$*`.  See also [what does "$@" mean in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script/9995322#9995322).

Comment: That works! Thanks. I prefer running it in background to have the terminal available for other commands imediately.

Comment: Yeah, sure, what I meant is: why do you mingle suppressing the output and sending it to the background?  With your solution you cannot suppress the output _without_ sending it to the background (e. g. to start this from a script which typically should wait until the other process is finished).  And without that `&` in `noout`, you could always append that `&` in the alias or on the commandline (if you happen to use `noout` directly).

Comment: That's a good comment. I haven't thought about using it in scripts yet. I have now created a new function `background(){"$@" &}` and changed the alias to `alias evince='background noout evince'`.

Comment: Tell me that's a joke ;-)

Comment: Note that `noout` will only work for very simple commands: no pipelines, no redirections, no other shell syntax, just a simple command name and its arguments.

Comment: Otherwise you will have to use sth like `noout bash -c 'ls | grep e'` to execute complexer stuff.  And you will run into quoting problems using this sooner or later.