# Packer can't execute shell provisioner as sudo

Tags: shell, root, provisioning, packer

I have a `shell provisioner` in packer connected to a box with user `vagrant`

```json
{
  "environment_vars": [
    "HOME_DIR=/home/vagrant"
  ],
  "expect_disconnect": true,
  "scripts": [
    "scripts/foo.sh"
  ],
  "type": "shell"
}
```

where the content of the script is:

```
whoami
sudo su
whoami
```

and the output strangely remains:

```
==> virtualbox-ovf: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/configureProxies.sh
    virtualbox-ovf: vagrant
    virtualbox-ovf: vagrant
```

why cant I switch to the root user?
How can I execute statements as root?
Note, I do not want to quote all statements like `sudo "statement |foo"` but rather globally switch user like demonstrated with `sudo su`

Comment: try this: https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html#sudo-example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should override the [execute_command](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html#execute_command). Example:

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E sh -eux '{{.Path}}'",
      "scripts": [
        "scripts/foo.sh"
      ],
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: But when using your solution `    virtualbox-ovf: bash: line 1: vagrant: command not found` is the output in case I want to switch back to the vagrant user for some other commands via `su vagrant`. Is there a solution for switching users which is better than my initial answer?

Comment: If you are `root` just prefix any command you want to run as another user with `sudo -u <user>`.

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution with simpler usage of 2 provisioner together.

Packer's shell provisioner can run the `bash` with `sudo` privileges. First you need copy your script file from local machine to remote with `file` provisioner, then run it with `shell` provisioner.

**`packer.json`**

```json
{
    "vars": [...],
    "builders": [
        {
            # ...
            "ssh_username": "<some_user_other_than_root_with_passwordless_sudo>",
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "scripts/foo.sh",
            "destination": "~/shell.tmp.sh"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": ["sudo bash ~/shell.tmp.sh"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**`foo.sh`**

```sh
# ...
whoami
sudo su root
whoami
# ...
```

**`output`**

```
<some_user_other_than_root_with_passwordless_sudo>
root
```

After provisioner complete its task, you can delete the file with shell provisioner.

**`packer.json`** *updated*

```json
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": ["sudo bash ~/shell.tmp.sh", "rm ~/shell.tmp.sh"]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

one possible answer seems to be:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70859/why-doesnt-sudo-su-in-a-shell-script-run-the-rest-of-the-script-as-root

```
sudo su <<HERE
ls /root
whoami
HERE
```

maybe there is a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the shell provisioner you are using is a bash script, you can add my technique to your script.

```sh
function if_not_root_rerun_as_root(){
    install_self
    if [[ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]]; then
        run_as_root_keeping_exports "$0" "$@"
        exit $?
    fi
}

function run_as_root_keeping_exports(){
    eval sudo $(for x in $_EXPORTS; do printf '%s=%q ' "$x" "${!x}"; done;) "$@"
}

export EXPORTS="PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE PACKER_BUILD_NAME"
if_not_root_rerun_as_root "$@"
```

There is a pretty good explanation of `"$@"` [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script).