# This shell script processes only one file

Tags: shell, unix, tags, mp3

I wanted to set the title and label of an mp3 file as the name of the file. For example, if **audio.mp3** is the name of the file, **audio** should be set as the title and label tags. To process all the mp3 files starting with letter **P**, I wanted to pass **P*mp3** as the command line parameter. My shell script is:

```
# mp3tag.sh
# Change title and label of mp3 files to file name
# Feb-25-2019

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo file name missing. Wild cards OK
    exit 1
fi

for i in $1; do 
    name=`echo $i | sed 's/....$//'` # Remove dot and mp3 from filename
    mp3info -t "$name" -l "$name" "$i"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Changed tags for "$i"
    else
        echo Error in changing tags for "$i"
    fi
done
```

This script processed only the first file **P1.mp3** in the directory, though I had files like P1.mp3, P2.mp3, .... Where have I gone wrong? Please help

Comment: have you tried `for i in $(ls $1); do` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard filename expansion is performed by the shell.  By the time your script runs, the shell has already expanded `P*mp3` into the actual list of filenames, and therefore `$1` is only the first filename.

Use `$*` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Actually, he should use `for i in "$@"; do` which is so common that it can be abbreviated as `for i; do`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9995322/1281485

Comment: Very nifty and it's a good reminder of my tip of iceberg knowledge, though I am using shell script since 1994. I would have marked yours as the most appropriate answer, if you had moved this from **Comments** to **Answers**.