# Dereference environment variable on parameter expansion in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-command

I am trying to dereference the value of environment variable using parameter expansion `$@`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I need to call a shell script with certain arguments. The list of arguments contain environment variables, and the environment variables are expected to be present where the shell script is to be executed. I do not know the list of commands before hand, so I am expanding those list of commands using `$@`. However, the script is not able to de-reference the value of environment variables.

A minimal setup which explains my problem can be done as below.

- Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ENV MY_VAR=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY run.sh .

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "run.sh" ]
```

- run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Value of MY_VAR is" $MY_VAR

echo "Begin"

$@

echo "Done"
```

I can build the image using `docker build . -t env-test`. When I run it using `docker run env-test:latest 'echo $MY_VAR'`, I get the below output.

```
Value of MY_VAR is production
Begin
$MY_VAR
Done
```

While the output that I am expecting is:

```
Value of MY_VAR is production
Begin
production
Done
```

SideNote: In actuality I am trying to run it using a compose file like below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  run:
    image: env-test:latest
    command: echo $$MY_VAR
```

but it again gives me the similar result.

Comment: Hey @LinPy, it doesn't work with even `ARG` instead of `ENV`

Comment: you can try using bash 'eval'  ?

Comment: Hey @DarrenSmith, yes I needed to put `eval`. Nice catch. If you post it as an answer, I can accept that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the `eval` approach, here is a simple bash script that will use eval to evaluate a string as a sequence of bash commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo program args:  $@
eval $@
```

but beware, `eval` comes with dangers:

https://medium.com/dot-debug/the-perils-of-bash-eval-cc5f9e309cae

Answer (score 1):

First thing, `$@` it will just print the number of argument

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Value of MY_VAR is" $MY_VAR

echo "Begin"

$@

echo "Done"
```

$@ = stores all the arguments in a list of string

$* = stores all the arguments as a single string

$# = stores the number of arguments

[What does $@ mean in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script/9995322)

Second thing, When run the below command

```
docker run env-test:latest 'echo $MY_VAR'
```

**It will look for $MY_VAR in host system not in the container.**

To access container env you have to pass them as `-e MY_VAR=test` ,not as argument to docker run command which will in the ENV in host.

```
docker run -e MY_VAR=test env-test:latest
```

So the value of `MY_VAR` will be `test` not `production`.

To debug the argument to `docker run`

```
export MY_VAR2="value_from_host"
```

Now run

```
docker run env-test:latest "echo $MY_VAR2"
```

so the value will `value_from_host` because thes argument pick from host.

Comment: Hey @Adiii, thanks for taking time to answer. However, the original question remains. Is there any way I can give a command, which contains environment variable from the container. So, in my case, somehow I give a command which contains the environment variable `MY_VAR`,  but the value is to be picked from container.

Comment: The reason being, the container is being spun by a system which populates the environment variable at run time, and there is no way to know the value of container environment variable by the host issuing the command.

Answer (score 0):

There are a more ways to skin this particular cat:

```
me@computer:~$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:20.04 bash -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
e610946f50c1
```

Here, we're calling on bash *inside the container* to process everything inside the single quotes, so variable substitution and/or expansion isn't applied by your shell, but by the shell inside the container.

Another approach is:

```
me@computer:~$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $HOSTNAME

me@computer:~$ cat test.sh | docker run -i --rm ubuntu:20.04 bash
62ba950a60fe
```

In this case, `cat` is "pushing" the contents of the script to `bash` the container, so it's functionally equivalent to my first example. The first method is "cleaner", however if you've got a more complex script, multi-line variables or other stuff that's difficult to put into a single command, then the second method is a better choice.

*Note: The hostname is different in each example, because I'm using the `--rm` option which discards the container once it exits. This is great when you want to run a command in a container but don't need to keep the container afterwards.*