# How to interpret if "$@" in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand this bash code but I'm pretty new on this. I'm not sure how to interpreter the next snippet. In more specific way I have doubts with the `if "@"; then` line.

```bash
check() {
    LABEL=$1
    shift
    echo -e "\n Testing $LABEL"
    if "$@"; then 
        echo "✅  Passed!"
        return 0
    else
        echoStderr "❌ $LABEL check failed."
        FAILED+=("$LABEL")
        return 1
    fi
}
```

I think that is just like the python list syntax to test an empty list the `if` will be success when the command tested return something. But I have doubts because bash use a lot error signals and I may be missing something. The use case is:

```bash
check "distro" lsb_release -c
check "color" [ $(cat /tmp/color.txt | grep red) ]
```

The snippeds were taken from this [repository](https://github.com/devcontainers/template-starter/blob/main/test/test-utils/test-utils.sh)

related question:
[What does mean $@ in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: That runs the command stored in `$@`, and if the result is successful (exitcode is 0) it runs the first part of the `if` statement; if the exit code is non-zero, it runs the `else` portion.

Comment: As a special case, if there are no arguments, the expansion of `"$@"` is empty and such a null command is defined to succeed.

Comment: The second use case is fragile. What `check` receives as arguments is the *result* of the command substitution, not the command substitution itself. (Further, if the command substitution produces more than one result, `[` is likely to fail with a syntax error.)

Comment: As for the function itself, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: I was totally wrong. I am grateful for your answers.

Comment: @larsks You might want to convert that to an answer so this can be marked as solved.

Comment: Extending chepner's comment: `check "color" grep -q red /tmp/color.txt` would be more robust