# Git permanent removal of file not resulting in smaller repo?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a repo that (at start) was 5.6G in size:

```
aparkin@mymachine ~/repo (master)
$ du -d 0 -h
5.6G    .
```

However, this repo contained a number of large binary files that no longer needed to be in the repo.  Originally they were in various locations in the directory structure, but all named "tc.dat".  As a "cleanup" step, I created a `cruft` directory, and `git mv` all of them into this cruft directory, changing their names to `tc.dat1`, `tc.dat2`, etc.

I then had 5 of these files, `tc.dat1` through `tc.dat5`

I then followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history), and used `filter-branch` along with the cleanup steps to remove all instances of these files in the `cruft` directory.  However, this still left the original filenames (before the move into `cruft`) in the repo.  I then repeated the step removing them from their original locations across all commits, and again did the cleanup steps:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune
```

After all this, if I do a

```
git log --all -- tc*.dat
```

I see no matches in my history, indicating to me that they are completely removed.  However, when I again do a `du` the repo is still 5.6G in size.  Given these files comprise about 0.5GB, I'd expect to see that number go down.

What am I missing?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892 (and the questions it refers to) be any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there were a few things I was missing.

Following the tips at [Git pull error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename/685422#685422) I tried some of the commands and did:

```
$ git-prune
$ git-prune-packed
$ du -h -d 0
5.2G
```

That's about 0.4G down, which is about the size of the files I wanted gone.  I also noticed in reading a [few other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797907/howto-remove-unused-objects-from-a-git-repsitory) and the man pages for `git-reflog` and `git-gc` that my usage of `reflog expire` and `--aggressive --prune` was incorrect.  Both take arguments as to how far back in history to go, and in both cases I want *all* history so the `now` parameter is needed:

```
$ rm -rf .git/refs/original/
$ git reflog expire --all --expire=now
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now
$ du -h -d 0
4.5G    .
```

A rather significant savings (1.1G) over what I started at.