# How can I archive old git tags?

Tags: git

I have some old tags in my git repository that are no longer important. I would like to archive the tags so that they don't show up by default when running git tag. I don't want to delete them, because I want to keep the history. How can I do this?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307114/how-can-i-archive-git-branches but my question is about tags instead of branches. (You archive branches by converting them to tags. But how do you archive tags?)

Comment: clone the repo, leave the tags in the backup, then delete them from the one you are working in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the repo, leave the tags in the backup, then delete them from the one you are working in.

(Note that @AndrewC wrote this answer in a comment to the question, but it counts as an answer to the question.)

Answer (score 11):

It's possible to keep the tags in the repo and avoid listing them as tags. It also avoids default clones from fetching them.

In origin (the bare repo) assuming you want to archive all tags starting with 'HIDE':

```
mkdir refs/archive
mv refs/tags/HIDE* refs/archive/
```

Now `git tag` will no longer list these refs, however they will still exist in the repository.

If you later want to pull down the archived tags to your local clone you can run the following:

```
git fetch origin +refs/archive/*:refs/archive/*
```

You can now list them using:

```
git for-each-ref refs/archive
```

Comment: Note that there is nothing special with the name 'archive', it could be named something else if wanted.

Comment: Won't their commits get garbage collected?

Comment: @DanFabulich No, the commit is still referenced, just not as a tag. If you run `git show-ref`for example in the bare repository you will see the archive references (or the for-each version that I mentioned in the answer). You can verify by forcing gc of everything, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14729486/11722) on the details of that - but read the warning before running that cmd.

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when you delete tags. Maybe a tag is the only reference to some sommit.

```
                      branch
                      |
                      V
 o---o---o----o---o---o
     \
      o---o---o---o
                  ^
                  |
                  someTag
```

If you remove the last reference to a commit you will loose the commit someday. Someday means as soon as [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) collects them.

If you don't have this problems you can use

```
$ git show-ref --tags > tag_refs-20141126.txt
```

to dump your tags and the commit ids to to a file. Then commit this file to your repository or keep it somewhere else.  After this you can delete the tags

```
$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/tags | cut -c11- | \
  while read tag; do git tag -d $tag; done
```

and restore them later

```
$ cat tag_refs-20141126.txt | while read commitid tagref; do echo $tagref $commitid; done \
  | cut -c11- | while read tagname commitid; do git tag $tagname $commitid; done
```

**EDIT**

I would prefer [Dan Fabulich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242889/974186) or [Zitrax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086361/974186)'s answer. Using hidden refs is what I also do. E.g. when I want to backup stashes. I wrote a [git extension](https://github.com/renelink/git-extensions/tree/main/stashes) for that some time ago.