# How can I archive old git tags and push my changes to origin?

Tags: bash, git

I'd like to get rid of some old tags. But I don't want to delete them, I just want to archive them so that I can restore them if necessary.

I am refering to the answer of a smiliar question: [How can I archive old git tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158574/how-can-i-archive-old-git-tags?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have created a new folder ref/archive/tags and moved all affected tags to this folder.

Suppose I can't make the changes directly in Origin, but have to do it in my local repository. How can I push the changes then?
I'm using the following command: 
    git push origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* 
    refs/archive/tags/*:refs/archive/tags/*

And receive the following feedback:
    Everything up-to-date
My colleagues can fetch the archive folder, but the old tags remain under refs/tags. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags will not be deleted from your coworker's repo unless he deletes them. Just like you can't change a tag without deleting it first. The other option is to clone your repo to a new directory.

To delete all local tags:

```
for x in `git tag`; do
git tag -d $x
done
git remote update
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used the following script. It archives all tags which are not named "test". Then all tags in the directory "refs/archive/tags" are deleted directly on the origin. Push the archive directory, delete all local tags and fetch the tags from origin. Maybe there are simpler solutions, but this one worked for me like this.

```
mkdir refs/archive/tags
shopt -s extglob
mv refs/tags/!(test) refs/archive/tags/
ls refs/archive/tags/ | xargs -n 1 -I% git push origin :refs/tags/%
git push origin refs/archive/tags/*:refs/archive/tags/*
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

My colleagues have to use the following script:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch origin +refs/archive/*:refs/archive/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Restore all tags if neccessary:

```
mv refs/archive/tags/* refs/tags/
git push origin --tags
```