# Why won’t git further reduce the repository size?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I have a repository with only one commit that has a checked out size of 95M.  However, I cannot get the .git folder size below 213M.  However, if I create a new repository with the same file contents, I get a .git folder of only 38M.

Is there a way to git to rebuild its objects in such a way as to get the size more in line with the figure from creating a new repository?

I tried both `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` and `git repack -adf --window=250 --depth=250` to reduce the repository size. They brought the repository down from the original 220M.

I imagine git must be keeping a references somewhere that prevents garbage collection, but I do not know where they would be.  I have removed all remotes and branches and I do not see anything other than my current branch under 'refs'

```
$ ls -R .git/refs
.git/refs/:
heads  tags

.git/refs/heads:
master

.git/refs/tags:
```

I created the repository from an existing one with longer history.  I used `checkout --orphan` to create a new baseless branch then did a commit to create a new commit with the state of the repository.  I then deleted the original branch and removed the remotes before running `gc`.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0
```

Comment: Clean out the reflogs, that's probably where things are hiding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce git repository size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)

Comment: @AndrewC That is what I tried to use and where I got the `gc` command above, but at the time it made no mention of the reflog.

Comment: I realized it was a circular reference after I marked it.  Whoops.  You'd think it would be somewhere but the stack overflow searching is so terrible.

Comment: No worries.  The great part about this is the answer for that question has now been updated which should keep more people from experiencing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running:

```
git reflog expire --all --expire=now
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

brought the folder down to 27M.  Thanks to @torek for the comment suggesting cleaning the reflog!

I had thought the reflog was not an issue because if I ran `git reflog` I only saw one entry, my single commit.  In response to @torek's suggestion I found [How to remove unused objects from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797907/how-to-remove-unused-objects-from-a-git-repository) which is where I found the command for clearing the reflog.