# Troubleshooting getting rid of large files in a git repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have a project called `geoplot` that does geospatial plotting in Python. The code for it is distributed via `git` on GitHub. [You can check it out here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot).

As a part of the development process for this package, I uploaded and stored in the `geoplot` repo a folder called `data/` which contained a large number of data files in various formats. These data files were used to populate the examples in the complimentary [example gallery](http://www.residentmar.io/geoplot/gallery.html).

However, these files bloat the overall repository size way up to ~150 MiB ([issue](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/37)). This is clearly way too much, and it's time for me to get rid of them.

The problem is that I need to not just remove these files from the current `HEAD`, I also scrub these files out of the entire `git` history. I tried a manual approach using `git rebase` that didn't work. Then I tried the `BFG Repo-Cleaner` tool, as recommended in [the canonical SO question on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository).

BFG rid me of the files alright—they no longer exist anywhere in the history. However, the size of the repo (as seen when running `https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot.git`) did not go down at all!

Here is what I tried (minus printouts):

```
java -jar ../bfg-1.12.15.jar --delete-folders "data" .
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push --set-upstream https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot.git master --force
```

The full printout is [in an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/37#issuecomment-330055790).

What, if anything, did I do wrong? How do I diagnose the source of and expunge this wasted space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did mention [`reflog` and `gc` back in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116892/6309), but also [removing old objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729486/6309).
(Note: [`gc` should be followed by a `repack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720432/6309))

First, check if by cloning your repo again, you still have the same size.

As the [OP Aleksey Bilogur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993206/aleksey-bilogur) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266906/troubleshooting-getting-rid-of-large-files-in-a-git-repository-on-github/46267401#comment79501723_46267401):

- you need make sure your tag are not referencing the old data, and then you need to force-push all the tags and branches as well (not just `master`)

  ```
  git push --tags origin --force
  ```
- generated data must be removed from the repo history.

Comment: I'm following the behavior described in the BFG docs (which is to say, I have little idea what these commands do, exactly). The repo still unpacks to the same total size; see [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/37#issuecomment-330067839).

Comment: How about the clone: does a fresh clone has the same size?

Comment: A fresh `git` clone is ~100 MiB. Anthony [suggested recreating the tags](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/issues/37), which helped, bringing the size of a tag down to 24 MiB.

Comment: However, now that I've handled the tags, I believe I know what the issue is---there are many example images in the repo that have been regened a few times that also need to be cleaned out.

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur OK. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility. Those are good advice that will help others.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an issue that could be solved without external tools, by leveraging `filter-branch`.

If you want to remove all history of the `data` directory, you can run the following from the root of your repo.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r path/to/data' HEAD
```

That will change every commit in the ancestry of your current `HEAD` pointer.  You would then have to update all other branches and tags to these newly created commits to completely remove the baggage from your repo.