# Reduce Historic Git Objects

Tags: git

I have a Bitbucket repository whereby there's a repo size limit of 2.0 GB. I had created a `.gitignore` but forgot to add the downloads/documents to it and thus the repo became 8.3 GB.

After I saw the notice in Bitbucket, I quickly ran

```
$ git rm -r /path/to/docs
```

After doing the usual `git add` etc. commands, I got this push error:

> repository is in read only mode (over 2 GB size limit).
>
> Learn how to reduce your repository size: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/xgMvEw.
>  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Which led me to use these commands:

```
$ du -sh project-root/
```

This returns:

> 6.0G project-root

This was a bit worrying as I just removed all of the documents, no way could it be that size. So I ran:

```
$ du --max-depth=10 -h project-root | sort -n -r
```

The directory that stands out most is:

```
5.7G    project-root/.git/objects/pack
5.7G    project-root/.git/objects
5.7G    project-root/.git
```

In turn, I ran `git gc` - but this had no effect (or at least in sizing terms).

So how do I reduce the size of my `.git/objects` directory? I imagine the size was contributed to by the large documents folders, but now they're gone. So how do I "clean" up my git objects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+directory+history

Comment: @phd also various search term links aren't constructive to the post or the SO community - to me it's just objects, I wouldn't have searched history at all..

Comment: @phd I must have clicked some other link thinking it was your dupe - because I didn't recognise any answers when I clicked into it again xD either way, the accepted answer is the correct one - as is the one I accepted on this post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing was pushed follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729486/1602555) which suggests additional `git gc` flags for more aggressive pruning.

You can rewrite the repository history and remove large files that should not be committed. This is explained in [Reducing the repository size using Git](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) and [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is suggested:

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing bad data out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

Comment: yee this works, the linked dupe goes into it a bit, both answers be good, so marked yours as accepted :)

Comment: Did you need to run BFG? Or was it enough to use `git gc`?

Comment: nah had to use BFG - I ran reset + gc a few times before posting this Q and it did nothing, so whatever BFG does under the hood works :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `git reset --hard`, which leaves it with only committed files or `git clean -d -x -f` that removes untracked files, including directories (-d) and files ignored by git (-x).

Take a look on:

[How do I clear my local working directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git)

[git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

[git-clean](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html)

Best regards,

Brhaka

Comment: I should have mentioned ^^ already done the reset :) but haven't done the clean, will let you know how it goes