# Cygwin and TortoiseGit

Tags: git, cygwin, tortoisegit

I have recently installed Cygwin along with the Git binaries and a copy of TortoiseGit on a fresh Windows XP install. I seem to be able to do most Git operations through TortoiseGit such as viewing the logs etc, but when I come to commit via TortoiseGit I get this message...

> error: unable to create temporary sha1
>   filename : No such file or directory

I am able to commit via the command line - I just dont seem able to commit through the gui interface!

Comment: maybe you should just use msysgit

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseGit is optimized for Git for Windows.

However, starting with TortoiseGit 1.8.13.0 Cygwin git can also be used with TortoiseGit.

You have to configure it as follows on TortoiseGit settings: Open TortoiseGit settings dialog and open the General page.

> 1) Select the [CYGWIN-INSTALL-PATH]\bin-folder as git.exe folder.
>
> 2) Configure the HOME environment variable in Windows, so that Cygwin
>   and TortoiseGit are using the same home directory and global
>   git-config. Use the normal Windows notation here (e.g.,
>   "C:\Users\USERNAME"). By default, TortoiseGit uses the Windows home
>   directory which is normally located under c:\Users and Cygwin uses its
>   own home directories which are located under
>   [CYGWIN-INSTALL-PATH]\home.
>
> 3) Configure AutoCrLf, this is necessary as TortoiseGit and Cygwin Git
>   have different defaults. The default in Cygwin Git is true.
>
> 4) Go to TortoiseGit the section called “Advanced Settings” and set
>   CygwinHack to true in order to activate cygwin workarounds.
>
> 5) Reboot.

Based on https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (decided to use git installed under cygwin instead of the one from msysgit).  Same thing: I was able to commit from the command line, and I was also able to see modification indicators and view logs in Tortoise, but I could not commit through the GUI.

What I had to do was to adjust the group settings of my project and the git executable. From one level above my project root, I ran the following command:

```
chgrp -R None my_project/
```

Then I did the following:

```
cd /bin
chgrp None git.exe
```

This changed the group of the git executable from what it was (`root`) to `None`.

Note that you may not want to use the `None` group.  Look at /etc/passwd and look at the fourth field of the line that starts with your user name (fields are colon-delimited and the first field is your user name)--that fourth field is your primary group ID.  Then look at /etc/group and find the line that has the same group ID as the *third* field.  That's the group name you want to use (in place of `None`) in the commands above.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: In my case everything is already None, so that isn't the fix for me. Not sure why you needed to do the chgrp, perhaps you installed git as a different user? Or maybe I am not seeing it because I am on FAT (vs. NTFS).

Answer (score 1):

This was known known issue, but its marked as fixed now. For background see https://tortoisegit.org/issue/56 and it's duplicate https://tortoisegit.org/issue/609.

Comment: Finally the workaround in comment 27 of the first link did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

The "unable to create temporary sha1 filename" issue was solved for me by:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/685422/431606

I simply ran `git repack` (from the command line) in my repository, and TortoiseGit was immediately able to commit.

(I still can't push through TortoiseGit, as I get the error message "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" as described in https://tortoisegit.org/issue/56)

Answer (score 0):

I tried those solutions, but they didn't work for me. What did work was to move all GIT related executables in the cygwin directory into a sub folder not in my path, then I installed the latest version of GIT from http://git-scm.com/, added the location of that installed GIT executable to my path, killed all instances of Windows Explorer & bash windows, launched a new instance of Windows Explorer, and then, I was able to commit via TortoiseGit. Currently (March 4, 2014) the cygwin version of GIT is 1.7.9, whereas the latest version from http://git-scm.com/ is 1.9.0. That seems to make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to reboot your machine. I had some trouble with a Tortoise installation once, but that solved the problem.