# I have Cygwin (1.7.17) and Git installed, how to run git (TortoiseGit 1.8.12.0) within cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, tortoisegit

I have Cygwin and Git installed on my machine. I do not have access to my machine so it was installed through admin. I am trying to run commands to install git within Cygwin but it is not working. I am running apt-cyg in Cygwin to install git but the command is not recognized. Also, tried to use this apt-cyg install git. Any idea?

Comment: Why not using a simple git for windows? Unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.2-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want (no admin right required) and you are good to go (and it comes with a git bash and 200+ Linux commands too). No need for cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to run TortoiseGit 1.8.12 with Cygwin as support for Cygwin was added in 1.8.13 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427358/3906760).

However, Running such an old version of git is not recommended as it contains unfixed security issues. Also such old versions of TortoiseGit are unsupported. Why not use git for Windows portable, which needs no installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [TortoiseGit's Settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) (Search keyword `Cygwin`)

> 1) Select the [CYGWIN-INSTALL-PATH]\bin-folder as git.exe folder.
>
> 2) Configure the HOME environment variable in Windows, so that Cygwin and TortoiseGit are using the same home directory and global git-config. Use the normal Windows notation here (e.g., "C:\Users\USERNAME"). By default, TortoiseGit uses the Windows home directory which is normally located under c:\Users and Cygwin uses its own home directories which are located under [CYGWIN-INSTALL-PATH]\home.
>
> 3) Configure AutoCrLf, this is necessary as TortoiseGit and Cygwin Git have different defaults. The default in Cygwin Git is true.
>
> 4) Go to TortoiseGit the section called “Advanced Settings” and set CygwinHack to true in order to activate cygwin workarounds.
>
> 5) Reboot.

**NOTE: There is no official support for Cygwin git in TortoiseGit.**

Cygwin hack is supported from TortoiseGit 1.8.13.

(Also see [Cygwin and TortoiseGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850236/cygwin-and-tortoisegit?lq=1))

Comment: 1.8.12 has no Cygwin hack