# fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Input/output error

Tags: git

What do I do about this?

```
git push
Counting objects: 30, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Input/output error
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

I tried the following from [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename) to a similar question

```
git repack
git prune
git gc --aggressive
```

Nothing helps.  The remote is a mounted AFS filesystem, I have been pushing to it without incident for a couple years.  I am not anywhere near quota, and I have permission (I can touch a file on this filesystem without problem).  Git version 1.7.5.4.

Comment: This might be due to a problem with the remote filesystem.  I am unable to copy a plain file to it without getting the input/output error.  Touch was an inadequate test because apparently a zero-length file can be created without problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this was, as indicated in the comment, a problem with the remote file server.  After waiting a while, I was able to push without incident.

Answer (score 10):

This is result of **disk quota exceeded**.
I got same error without additional explanation.  I then noticed that my disk quota was exceeded.  After freeing some disk space, i was able to perform the original git action.

PS: In my case, the error condition prevent any change in the **local** git repository.  I was not able to do any of add/commit/push/gc (all gave above sha1 file error).