# What is the algorithm git uses to find a commit by a partial sha-1 (at least first 4 characters)?

Tags: algorithm, git, sha

What is the algorithm git uses to find a commit by a partial sha-1 (at least first 4 characters).
Are there any implementations of such algorithm out there?

Comment: Have you checked the source code?

Comment: This question is off-topic because Stack Overflow is for questions about writing code.

Comment: To me this question makes sense and looks a valid Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 3):

One very simple way (but ineffective) to find the full SHA1 given a partial "`01234`" one (a "[short SHA1](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#A-SHORT-NOTE-ABOUT-SHA-1)")is:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | grep ^01234
```

The actual way is:

```
git rev-parse --verify 01234
```

It is illustrated in [commit 6269b6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6269b6b676310d9fa2560da49be618372b39acf4)

> Teach `get_describe_name()` to pass the disambiguation hint down the
>   callchain to `get_short_sha1()`.

So you can see the algorithm in [sha1_name.c#get_short_sha1()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6269b6b676310d9fa2560da49be618372b39acf4/sha1_name.c#L227) function, which will looks in:

- [objects](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6269b6b676310d9fa2560da49be618372b39acf4/sha1_name.c#L265): `find_short_object_filename(len, hex_pfx, &ds);`
- and in [pack files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685422/6309): `find_short_packed_object(len, bin_pfx, &ds);`
  (See "[Git Internals - Packfiles](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles)")