# Why git stores copy of whole file for single line change?

Tags: git, filesystems, compression, dvcs

Say we go for a sample run:

```
git init
echo -e 'hede\nhodo' > new.txt
git add new.txt
git commit -m 'commit 1'
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
echo -e 'hede\n123' > new.txt
git add new.txt
git commit -m 'commit 2'
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

So I know SHA of two versions. When I look into them, I see:

```
git cat-file -p ad0daa422be9531700a069e6800b18c065f755bb
hede
hodo

git cat-file -p 6fbf5b80b76bbe270bb41789c34851d622ae1f63
hede
123
```

It seems git copied blob, but 'hede' remained redundant. I know it is not a big impact for small files but just asking: Does git optimize this into differences later on? Or is this the way what makes git efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files and note the comment by Jan Hudec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mention in "[How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/6309)", Git:

- manages content (which is why you see 2 complete blobs)
- stores internally delta (and achieve an high-compression level that way, though **[pack files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685422/6309)**)

So it is efficient when it matters (clone/push/pull), while providing easy and *quick* access locally.

Comment: Thank you that was the information I was looking for. Jan Hudec's comment is clear as well.