# Odd behavior when Git repo is in C:\Program Files

Tags: git, permissions, administrator

We have a Git repo in C:\Program Files\Some-DB\Some-DB-Queries. When Git (or SourceTree) is run as Admin, everything works as expected. However, as non-Admin, after pulling into a local repo, Git sees those changes as uncommitted local changes.

Does Git have to be run as Admin in Windows? If not, is there a way to configure security such that Git has the proper permissions for a repo living in Program Files?

Comment: When programs write to certain areas that a normal user generally doesn't have access, UAC virtualization comes to the confusing rescue: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx .  The moral of this story is:  Don't keep your data in program files.

Comment: @IronSavior Thanks. Regarding Program Files, the database requires query modules to be descendants of the database application directory, so moving the files out of Program Files is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't explain why your repository has to live there.

Comment: @IronSavior If the working folder is still in Program Files, I don't see how that helps solve the problem with permissions.

Comment: The other option would be to either change the permissions on the folder containing your repository and working directories, or to always run git using an admin account (or otherwise an account with permission).   I'm not sure what you need to do in order to forsake the UAC-virtualized copy, though.