# Git Garbage collection doesnt seem to fully work

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I'm a little confused as how to completely clean out my garbage...

**git count-objects -v -H**

```
warning: garbage found: ./objects/pack/gc_7174754666377259454.idx_tmp
warning: garbage found: ./objects/pack/gc_7174754666377259454.pack_tmp
warning: garbage found: ./objects/pack/pack-f5b13f50fe2e4d773028c51f547822e6f2fe720b.bitmap
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 32986
packs: 1
size-pack: 44.14 MiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 3
size-garbage: 41.20 MiB
```

So that implies to me I have 41 megs of garbage in my repo?

**git gc --prune=now --aggressive**

```
Counting objects: 32986, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (31610/31610), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32986/32986), done.
Total 32986 (delta 23902), reused 9080 (delta 0)
```

And when I run count objects again i still have the same output with

```
    size-garbage: 41.20 MiB
```

Do I just manually delete the garbage files?  At least one is quite plump at the very least.

```
12/02/2014  02:06 PM                 0 gc_7174754666377259454.idx_tmp
12/02/2014  02:06 PM        43,195,455 gc_7174754666377259454.pack_tmp
               2 File(s)     43,195,455 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  502,905,999,360 bytes free
```

Comment: see if you have better luck with `git repack -ad`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>git log -Ssize-garbage|more
```

This show the `size-garbage` output has been introduced in [commit 1a20dd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a20dd49f8c4e6c62080f267ca77b357cb61be8e) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) for git 1.8.3 (May 2013)

> `size-garbage`: disk space consumed by garbage files, in KiB
>
> #### `count-objects`: report how much disk space taken by garbage files
>
> Also issue warnings on **loose garbages** instead of errors as a result of
>   using `report_garbage()` function in `count_objects()`

This [garbage cleaning tip section](http://gitolite.com/tips-3.html) mentions:

> To bring the repo size down the bare minimum, you need both the following commands (**neither command by itself does the whole job**).
>   Also Note the lowercase "`a`" on the "`repack`", which says you want to blindly discard unreachable objects instead of keeping them as loose objects.

```
git repack -adf     # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

So try again the `git count-objects -v -H` after applying *both* commands.

---

Looking at the [`git repack` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack), [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257399/git-garbage-collection-doesnt-seem-to-fully-work/28563637#comment45449530_28563637):

> I prefer the big-`A` option:

> "Same as `-a`, unless `-d` is used.
>   Then any unreachable objects in a previous pack become loose, unpacked objects, instead of being left in the old pack."

> Linus Torvalds argues that `-f` like `gc`'s `--aggressive` is much overused -- [so much so he suggested yanking the documentation for it](http://markmail.org/message/gv4uua6ffsuhhjyt).
>   (in 2007)
>   (`-f` is for `--no-reuse-delta`)

That means a more efficient combination might be:

```
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

Comment: I prefer the big-A option, "Same as -a, unless -d is used. Then any unreachable objects in a previous pack become loose, unpacked objects, instead of being left in the old pack."  Linus Torvalds argues that `-f` like gc's `--aggressive` is much overused -- so much so [he suggested yanking the documentation for it](http://markmail.org/message/gv4uua6ffsuhhjyt).

Comment: @jthill Interesting. I didn't know about that 2007 thread. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you for that link, @jthill. That was an incredible interesting and educational read.