# How to delete incomplete pull files in git?

Tags: git

I accidently ran command `git pull <wrong_remote_url>` in my repository. During the pull process, I cancel it by click `Ctrl+C`.

```
$ du -h -d 1
20M .  # At first the repository is only 20M
$ git status
OK
$ git pull https://example.com/large_repository.git  # accidently pull the wrong repository
press Ctrl + C during the pull  # cancel it during the pull, because I find it is downloading a lot of large file
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ du -h -d 0
2.1G .  # Now the repository is too large
$ du -h -d 0 .git
2.1G .git  # There may be a lot of cached and useless file in .git directory
```

The repository still works, I can still use git as usual and the extra `2G` file will not be pushed to repository. But I know there is about `2G` cached file in the `.git` directory. How can I delete these files? I tryied `git gc` and `git clean`, but they don't work. For some reason, there is some database data in the repository, so I don't want to delete the repository and clone it again.

---

I find the tmpfile in `.git/objects/pack/` named as `tmp_pack_9qTKaE`, `tmp_pack_CKZSuG`, etc.
I think it is the large, useless cached file. It works if I delete them:

```
rm -f .git/objects/pack/tmp_*
```

Is there any command in git I can delete these file automatically and safely?

Answer (score 2):

run command

```
git repack -Ad
git prune
```

I get this answer from [this answer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778198/3601654). More documentation can been seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257399/git-garbage-collection-doesnt-seem-to-fully-work/28563637#28563637). After running these two commands, the tmp files in `.git/objects/pack` have been deleted.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is slightly off-topic, I'll add this to the previous answers :

If you're realizing mid-pull you're pulling on the wrong local branch, or pulling the wrong remote one, do NOT interrupt it.

It'll be way easier to let it finish then `git merge --abort` it.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I tried your solution, it showed `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. When I ran `git merge --abort it`, it showed `fatal: There is no merge to abort`. Maybe you misunderstand my situation, I pull the wrong repository not just the wrong branch.