# Why are pack files less in size than the objects of the remote repo?

Tags: git, git-clone

When we clone a remote we get we get instead of object packed files which seems to be some performance optimization to reduce size.
But how is this optimization done? If I understand these are binary files with the same contents as the original objects so how exactly they occupy less space? Is the implementation some standard one?

Comment: Maybe you don't get the deleted refs?

Comment: Because they are compress? Why `C` tag?

Comment: @Stargateur:Git is written in C right? So maybe it is about the way we write binary files in compact manner in C? Some standard pattern? How are they compressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Git's pack files deltas rather than snapshots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176225/are-gits-pack-files-deltas-rather-than-snapshots)

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in "[How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/6309)", Git does use deltas for storage.

The result includes [pack files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685422/6309), using a [custom implementation of a diff algo for delta computation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309).