# Git pull - No space left on device error with free space left

Tags: git, git-pull

I get this error when trying to git pull:

> remote: Counting objects: 6, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>   (6/6), done. remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) error:
>   unable to create temporary sha1 filename : No space left on device
>
> fatal: failed to write object fatal: unpack-objects failed

I checked and I use only 57% of disk space, and have plenty of free space for the pull action. 
Last pull was about a week ago and there was no such problem. 
What can be the reason?

My question is not a duplicate with [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename)
The problem there is the object already exists, while my problem is that I get no free space error while `df -h` shows only 57% percent usage.

Comment: could you try to run `git gc` and then pull again?

Comment: I think its duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename

Comment: From experience, when a process is reporting there is `no space left on device` and you think there is still space left, in the overwhelming majority of cases you are wrong and the process is right (a little bit like when a compiler reports a syntax error you cannot directly spot with your eyes). There can be a lot of reasons (the method you used to check free space, the remaining space which is not sufficient for your operation, a COW filesystem blotted with snapshots, looking at the wrong device, ...)

Comment: @Vishal it's not. I actually saw that one, and although the error looks similar it's not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pull error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have disk space, it may be `inodes`. Check the amount of `inodes` left on the disk(if you're using Linux / Mac) with the following command:

```
df -ih
```

From wikipedia:

> The inode (index node) is a data structure in a Unix-style file system that describes a file-system object such as a file or a directory. Each inode stores the attributes and disk block location(s) of the object's data. File-system object attributes may include metadata (times of last change, access, modification), as well as owner and permission data.

The amount of files on the disk matter, so try clearing some files on the disk (not large files, either).

Comment: Tha't is! Thank you.